# Autocompleting in Emacs adds ^M after having used octave plot command

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, octave

I use `M-x run-octave` to trigger octave in emacs, everything works fine until I plot something, after that hit `Tab` would complete my input (say plo -> plot) but there is an annoying `^M` in the end. So `awg` then hit `Tab` would get `awgn ^M`.

Does someone have a similar problem or any suggestion?

Comment: are you running emacs on windows?

Comment: No, I am running it under ubuntu 11.10, I bet it's not the dos/unix encode thing.

Comment: I have something similar happening; however I think it is only cosmetic.  Octave doesn't seem to mind the extra character.

Answer (score 0):

The real fix would be to be able to tell Octave to DTRT.

Try setting the buffer's end-of-line behavior, using `C-x RET f` and then specifying `dos`.  If that works it's only because the `^M` chars are then hidden.  IOW, it's a workaround.  Unless, that is, Octave is just doing the wrong thing because it doesn't bother to check the buffer eol setting.  Consider also filing an Octave bug.